# For a bandpass transfer function, are there two gain bandwidth products?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, transfer-function

Every example I have come across shows the gain bandwidth product used only for low pass transfer functions, but I never see it used for bandpass or in fact high pass transfer functions. Why is this?

Comment: Is this an active filter using an op-amp? In that case, because in the case of HPF or BPF, the op-amp bandwidth doesn't restrict the low-frequency band edge, so the concept of GBW product doesn't apply. It will restrict the maximum frequency able to pass, even if the filter is nominally an HPF.

Comment: This is regarding op-amps

Comment: The gain bandwidth product makes sense for an op-amp **as a device**, but not for a filter that you might build with an op-amp -- in that case, you just care about bandwidth, because in signal processing terms adding gain is trivial.  Similarly, you care about the bandwidth of a bandpass filter, but not it's gain bandwidth product.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about an op-amp based active filter it's because the op-amp GBW product doesn't really restrict the bandwidth of the design. It restricts the highest frequency the design will be able to pass.

So even if the design is an HPF, the op-amp's GBW product will restrict the maximum frequency the design is able to pass.

Or if it's an BPF, it restricts the maximum the high-frequency cut-off of the filter can be and still operate according to the usual design equations.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this comparison of two opamps: 1MHz and 50MHz Gain BandWidth.

The default BandPass center frequency is 10KHz. Both slow and fast opamps achieve that.

However the slow opamp no longer attenuates out past 100,000Hz.

The fast opamp provides controlled attenuation past 1MHz.

For both opamps, the C2 provides a path **AROUND** the opamp for high frequencies.

[image]

For both opamps, the opamp Rout, interacting with the input resistive divider R1 and R5, determines the attenuation at high frequencies.

The 1MHz opamp is modeled with Rout of 100 ohms.

The 50MHz opamp, MCP655, is modeled with Rout of 30 ohms.

The ratio of 100/30 = 3.3, thus we'd expect about 10dB more attenuation at high frequencies for the MCP655 50MHz opamp.

However the value of R5 is so low, at 48 ohms, that the OpAmp Rout does poorly at setting the voltage division ratio.

Can you use this circuit as an anti-alias filter for an ADC? Not with high-frequency behavior such as this. You need an additional **PASSIVE** RC low pass filter, passive to ensure the frequency response does not depend on the performance of any gainblock/opamp.